# How to stop double request to same url

Tags: angularjs

Angularjs app here.
There are 2 controllers that do similar things.
In particular, they have an interval. Each 10 seconds they go to their own service.

These 2 different services also do similar things. Most important is that they go to an URL that looks like this:

```
example.com/fromTimestamp=2019-11-21T15:13:51.618Z
```

As the two controllers start more or less at the same time, in the example above they could generate something like:

```
controller/service 1:           example.com/fromTimestamp=2019-11-21T15:13:51.618Z
controller/service 2:           example.com/fromTimestamp=2019-11-21T15:13:52.898Z
```

This is because the parameter is created in the service with his line:

```
var timestamp = fromTimestamp ? '&fromTimestamp=' +fromTimestamp.toISOString() : '';
```

So maybe there will be a difference of some seconds. Or even only a difference of milliseconds.

I would like to make only one request, and share the data fetched from http between the two services.
The most natural approach would seem to be using cache. 
What I could understand is that this call could make the trick:

```
return $http.get('example.com/fromTimestamp=2019-11-21T15:13:51.618Z', {cache: true});
```

But looking in the dev tools it is still making 2 requests to the server. I guess this is because they have 2 different urls?
If that is the problem, what could be another approach to this problem?

Comment: Is stripping off the seconds on the timestamp an option? You stated that you are making two requests, even if the difference is only a couple of seconds. That is a design / architectural decision you have to make to centralize the API call perhaps so that if you know that one request has been made and the next request is similar to the timestamp albeit a few seconds difference, then you can re-use the data provided by the previous api call.

Comment: seconds need to be sent. I cannot just send minute.

Comment: If you need to send seconds, then that pretty much sums up the fact that you need to send two requests as the differences in the seconds itself changes the whole API url (or parameter). Calling `https://myapi.ca/time=2019-11-20T12:00:00.000Z` is different when calling `https://myapi.ca/time=2019-11-20T12:00:00.001Z` even if it is a microsecond difference. You will have to put some check on your code to determine when the last API call was made with the timestamp and design a threshold for when to perform the next call again.

Comment: @Angelo the differrence between those two times is a **millisecond**, not microsecond. JavaScript time values are stored as millisconds from 1970-01-01T00:00.000Z.

Answer (score 1):

In my apps, when face with this problem, I use the `$q` provider and a promise object to suspend all calls to the same endpoint while a singleton promise is unresolved.

So, if the app makes two calls very close together, the second call will not be attempted until the promise created by the first call is resolved. Further, I check the parameters of the calls, and if they are the same, then the original promise object is returned for both requests. In your case, your parameters are always different because of the time stamp. In that case, you could compare the difference in time between the two calls, and if it is under a certain threshold in miliseconds, you can just return that first promise object. Something like this:

```
var promiseKeeper; //singleton variable in service
function(endpointName, dataAsJson) {
      if (
        angular.isDefined(promiseKeeper[endpointName].promise) &&
        /*promiseKeeper[endpointName].dataAsJson == dataAsJson && */
        lastRequestTime - currentRequestTime < 500
      ) {
        return promiseKeeper[endpointName].promise;
      } else {
        deferred = $q.defer();
        postRequest = $http.post(apiUrl, payload);
        postRequest
          .then(function(response) {
            promiseKeeper[endpointName] = {};
            if (params.special) {
              deferred.resolve(response);
            } else {
              deferred.resolve(response.data.result);
            }
          })
          .catch(function(errorResponse) {
            promiseKeeper[endpointName] = {};
            console.error("Error making API request");
            deferred.reject(extractError(errorResponse));
          });
        promiseKeeper[endpointName].promise = deferred.promise;
        promiseKeeper[endpointName].dataAsJson = dataAsJson;
        return deferred.promise;
      }
}
```